# How to use IN operator for satisfy all values inside?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am having one table `specification_master` with 3 fields.

1. spec_id
2. spec_value
3. spec_main_id

I am having below data inside table:

```
spec_id | spec_value | spec_main_id
11      | abc.com    | 10001
12      |            | 10001
13      |            | 10001
11      | xyz.com    | 10002
12      | google.com | 10002
13      | mozzila.com| 10002
```

Now I want data where spec_value is not blank:

And for this query is:

```
select spec_id, spec_value, spec_main_id 
from specification_master 
where spec_main_id IN (10001,10002) 
    AND spec_id IN (11,12) 
    AND spec_value != ''
```

By this I am getting data for `10001` also but I want data for `10002` only as per my query.

Desired result:

```
spec_id | spec_value | spec_main_id 
11      | xyz.com    | 10002 
12      | google.com | 10002
```

Comment: SELECT DISTINCT .... maybe? Question is not clear to me.

Comment: Please show the desired result in the question.

Comment: spec_id | spec_value | spec_main_id
11      | xyz.com    | 10002
12      | google.com | 10002  @Barmar

Comment: Put it in the question so you can format it properly.

Comment: Your query only selects one column, why do you expect 3 columns in the result?

Comment: @Barmar that is typo. Did you undestand now what i exactly want.I cant get option to Edit question.

Comment: So you want the `spec_id` that has both `spec_main_id` = 10001 and 10002, but only the row with non-empty `spec_value`.

Comment: yes correct. By this With my query i want only data of `10002` spec_main_id

Answer (score 0):

You are filtering on each record individually, so you are getting all of the `spec_main_id` of the records that have a `spec_value` filled (which includes getting the id duplicated). So you get the `10001` because in fact there are records where the `10001` has `spec_value` populated.

What it seems that you want: `spec_main_id` that has NO records with `spec_value` empty. To do that, since this id repeats itself for a **group** of records, you'll want to **group by** the id and get the `MIN` `spec_value` for any given group. If the group has a empty value, that will be the min value, if it doesn't, all values are populated.

```sql
select spec_main_id, MIN(spec_value) as min_spec_value
from specification_master 
where spec_main_id IN (10001,10002) AND spec_id IN (11,12) 
group by spec_main_id
having min_spec_value != ''
```

SQL fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9072a2/3/0

Hope that helps.

Comment: @reg_arg thanks for your reply but this is not i want. I dont need MIN().. O/P should be xyx.com , google.com

Comment: @amitsutar why shouldn't `abc.com` and `mozzila.com` be returned?